# Trouble in Hadoop installation on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: hadoop

Problem in testing ssh with hduser [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFXAc.png)

During setting up hadoop single node cluster, I had a problem while doing SSH setup by connecting to local machine with the `hduser` user.

The solutions given by Michael Noll doesn't seem to work as the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file doesn't have option of `PubkeyAuthentication` and is read only file.

Can anyone please help me out with it?

Comment: `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` can't be edited by regular users, that's why it appears read-only. Did you try `sudo vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config` on it? Can you also post the link to the solution you tried?

Comment: I had to installed openssh server. the steps in michael noll's site work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your ssh localhost Is not working then try this

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server 
sudo apt-get install ssh-server rsync

ssh-keygen -t rsa -P “”
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

And on all slaves copy the id_rsa.pub content of master node to authorized_keys file in slaves

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with setting up ssh. I then followed this tutorial and i was able to install hadoop succesfully in ubuntu.http://preciselyconcise.com/apis_and_installations/hadoop_installation.php